# Replace Azure DevOps pipeline parameters(runtime) within file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am new to Azure DevOps and what I am trying to do is to replace a parameter's value that is defined within the `.yml` file(parameter itself having a default value) with the one that is selected manually when running the pipeline. I have tried using the `FileTransform@1` task but without any success although it works with a defined pipeline variable.

Just wondering is it even possible to do this via `FileTransform@1` task or at all with any other task or a custom script.

Maybe the suggested approach is to use a variable instead of a parameter.

This is how my `.yml` file looks like:

```
parameters:
  - name: language
    default: 'klingon'
    type: string

  - task: FileTransform@1
    inputs:
      folderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      fileType: 'json'
      targetFiles: '**/appsettings.json'
```

My `appsettings.json` file looks like:

```
{
  "language": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `FileTransform@1` task works with a defined pipeline variable, you can define the variable `language` based on the parameter `languagevalue`.

```
parameters:
  - name: languagevalue
    default: 'klingon'
    type: string

variables:
- name: language
  value: ${{ parameters.languagevalue }} 
  
steps:
  - task: FileTransform@1
    inputs:
      folderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      fileType: 'json'
      targetFiles: '**/appsettings.json'
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you, appreciate it.